# Difference between packed vs normal data type

Tags: swift, types, metal

In Metal what is the difference between a `packed_float4` and a `float4`?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MetalShadingLanguageGuide/data-types/data-types.html

Comment: I have read that documentation. It does not tell you what a packed data type is. It simply discloses that they are available in Metal.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This information is from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MetalShadingLanguageGuide/data-types/data-types.html)

`float4` has an alignment of `16` bytes. This means that the memory address of such a type (e.g. `0x12345670`) will be divisible by `16` (aka the last hexadecimal digit is `0`).

`packed_float4` on the other hand has an alignment of `4 bytes`. Last digit of the address will be `0`, `4`, `8` or `c`

This does matter when you create custom structs. Say you want a struct with 2 normal `float`s and 1 `float4`/`packed_float4`:

```
struct A{
    float x, y;
    float4 z;
}

struct B{
    float x, y;
    packed_float4 z;
}
```

For `A`: The alignment of `float4` has to be `16` and since `float4` has to be after the normal `float`s, there is going to be `8` bytes of empty space between `y` and `z`. Here is what `A` looks like in memory:

```
 Address | 0x200 | 0x204 | 0x208 | 0x20c | 0x210 | 0x214 | 0x218 | 0x21c |
 Content |   x   |   y   |   -   |   -   |   z1  |   z2  |   z3  |   z4  |
                                             ^Has to be 16 byte aligned
```

For `B`: Alignment of `packed_float4` is `4`, the same as `float`, so it can follow right after the `float`s in any case:

```
 Address | 0x200 | 0x204 | 0x208 | 0x20c | 0x210 | 0x214 |
 Content |   x   |   y   |   z1  |   z2  |   z3  |   z4  |
```

As you can see, `A` takes up `32` bytes whereas `B` only uses `24` bytes. When you have an array of those structs, `A` will take up `8` more bytes for every element. So for passing around a lot of data, the latter is preferred.

The reason you need `float4` at all is because the GPU can't handle `4` byte aligned `packed_float4`s, you won't be able to return `packed_float4` in a shader. This is because of performance I assume.

One last thing: When you declare the Swift version of a struct:

```
struct S {
    let x, y: Float
    let z : (Float, Float, Float, Float)
}
```

This struct will be equal to `B` in Metal and *not* `A`. A tuple is like a `packed_floatN`.

All of this also applies to other vector types such as `packed_float3`, `packed_short2`, ect.