# Is there any speed penalty to use **packed** vertex structure?

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

I have this declaration in my metal shader implementation:

```
    struct InVertex {
      packed_float3 pos;
      packed_float2 textureCoord;
      packed_uchar4 color;
    };
```

Is there any speed penalty to use **packed** declaration ? If yes how to measure it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf)

- You cannot use the **stage_in** attribute to declare members of the structure that are **packed**
  vectors, matrices, structures, bitfields, references or pointers to a type, or arrays of scalars,
  vectors, or matrices.
- MSL functions and arguments have these additional restrictions:
   The return type of a vertex or fragment function cannot include an
  element that is a **packed** vector type, matrix type, a structure type,
  a reference, or a pointer to a type.
- You can use an array index to access components of a **packed** vector data type. However, you
  cannot use the .xyzw or .rgba selection syntax to access components of a **packed** vector data
  type.

> Is there any speed penalty to use **packed** vertex structure?

It's described very well in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38773807/difference-between-packed-vs-normal-data-type), in short you would benefit from using it, in terms of speed, especially when passing around a lot of data.

Comment: thanks @0xBFE1A8 ! I updated a little my question because i want mostly to know about speed penalty